Let $f, g \in A(\mathbb{D}^n)$ and $x,y \in \mathbb{D}^n$. What is $\langle (f \cdot g)(x), y \rangle$ equal to or bounded from above by?
Here, let $f, g \in A(\mathbb{D}^n)$, which is the polydisc algebra and $x,y \in \mathbb{D}^n$.
What would $\langle (f \cdot g)(x), y \rangle$ be equal to? If no equality, by what would it be bounded from above?
I looked everywhere on the internet, couldn't find anything remotely related to this. I am not looking for the Schwarz inequality, what I want to obtain are two scalar products (like $\langle f(x), y \rangle$ and $\langle g(x), y \rangle$ e.g. multiplied with each other or something like that). This is very, very crucial and I need $\langle f(x), y \rangle$ and $\langle g(x), y \rangle$ in order to solve a problem I'm currently working on.

I don’t see the relevance of $f,g$. What can you say about $\langle zw,y\rangle$?
